# ArrayCollection in PHP

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

How can i return my output in ArrayCollection?

```
values = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            $values[] = array(mysql_num_rows($result),$row['userlevel'],$row['email'],$row['member_id']);
        }
        return $values;
```

I need the output as ArrayCollection

Comment: ArrayCollection is not part of PHP that I'm aware of...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has no such thing as an ArrayCollection as far as I'm aware.

From a quick Google search it seem like this is more about ActionScript/Flex. [This page](http://wadearnold.com/blog/flash/amfphp/amfphp-arraycollection) has some examples of how to get an ArrayCollection from a PHP array. Not sure if it's what you're looking for though.

Answer (score 13):

`ArrayCollection` is part of [Collections](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/collections.html), a Doctrine project.

There is no published documentation but the available methods can be seen in the [`ArrayCollection` class](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php) itself.

Comment: Please cite some of the linked text in your answer. It is valid, but if that link breaks, so does this answer. Just the class name and authors would help someone find it if (for some reason) the link did not work.

Answer (score 1):

If what others are saying is true, and you're referring to implementation of [ActionScript's ArrayCollection](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html) in PHP, then from [that example](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html) I conclude you're talking about what everyone else calls *associative arrays* or *dictionaries*. If that is so, I'll be happy to tell you that array object, as returned by PHP's `array()` function, already incorporates all you need.

If you would be so kind to clarify what exactly you mean by ArrayCollection, we might be able to help you better (and earn our up-points) :-)

Answer (score 0):

See this:

[`http://groups.google.com/group/flex_india/browse_thread/thread/f7af9f284216732e`](http://groups.google.com/group/flex_india/browse_thread/thread/f7af9f284216732e)

I'm guessing you're talking about a FLEX ArrayCollection.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayObject class in php (spl) comes close to idea of ArrayCollection in as3.